# Displaying Current Amazon Prices In Website

Tags: web-services, web

This is just a general question, but I'm wondering if there's an existing API that displays the current price for an item on Amazon? As in, if the price changes, the site will reflect that change as well.

If not, would building a web crawler to go through and find the Amazon items of my choice be the best way to build my own version of this? If so, what language would you recommend to begin this sort of project.

I'm not sure if I should have actually asked this in SuperUser but I appreciate the input. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of web crawling services for this task.

- https://import.io/
- https://www.kimonolabs.com/
- http://www.diffbot.com/

If you want to make your own, I recommend node.js because it's asynchronous behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at these.